# If extra dimensions are out there, why don't/can't we see them?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, geometry, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

String theory proposes the existence of extra space dimensions. Very brilliant minds believe in their existence.

Of course, I could appreciate that they are consequences of mathematical consistencies of String theory. Also, Einstein's theory of gravity is consistent with any number of space dimensions, and there is no sane reason why should the universe must be $3+1$ dimensional or cannot have more than $3$ space dimensions. So extra dimensions could really exist. I don't deny that; don't get me wrong.

But I cannot get my head around that if extra space dimensions are really out there, why can't we see them? I never did understand this. The answer often offered is that since these extra dimensions are small we cannot see them. I can understand microscopic objects in $3$ dimensions cannot be seen but I cannot understand how could dimensions themselves cannot be seen.

Comment: How would you know if you were constantly moving around in a compact dimension smaller than a proton? There is effectively “nowhere to go”.

Comment: @G.Smith Interesting. Does it have the possibility that visible light having a long wavelength cannot "interact" in any way with those tiny dimensions making them literally invisible? Also, do we experience ordinary three dimensions by literally seeing them through visible light or we just experience them? I don't know if now I am asking a philosophical question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra Dimensions (in String Theory) - What does it mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476620/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These extra dimensions are very small, on the order of the Planck length, they also wrap around. Eg, if *w* is a compactified dimension, if you travel in the *w* direction you quickly get back to where you started, like in those computer games (eg Asteroids) where if you go off the right side of the screen you reappear on the left side.

The original theory that introduced a compactified dimension is [Kaluza-Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory), which unites GR with electromagnetism. In that theory, momentum in the extra dimension equates to electric charge. So the extra dimension is kind of visible, in that we can certainly detect charge, but it just doesn't "look" the same as the uncompactified space dimensions.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the extra dimension in the KK theory being compactified?

Comment: @safesphere See the Wikipedia link. "Klein introduced the hypothesis that the fifth dimension was curled up and microscopic, to explain the cylinder condition."

Comment: @PM2Ring I think we can be convinced about the possible existence of extra space dimensions in the following way. Space seems to be 3-dimensional because it does not require more than three independent numbers to locate a point. However, this conclusion is experimental or based on human scale observation. However, experimentally when we locate a point, it's not a mathematical point; we are identifying a region of finite extension as a point. Unless we could observe below the length scale of that region, we cannot be sure whether three coordinates are sufficient. What do you think about this?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Yes, that's feasible, but there are extra complications, eg, we may not be able to see or move into the extra dimension(s) for some reason. Also, at small scales (atom size and smaller), classical notions of geometry become less useful, due to Heisenberg uncertainty. The Planck length is *much* smaller than an atom. At the Planck scale, uncertainty may affect the geometry of spacetime itself, according to some approaches to quantum gravity.

Answer (score 1):

The best familiar analogy I have been able to produce is the surface of Velcro that is covered in tiny hooks. If you imagine that the Velcro surface was considerably reduced in size you would be unable either to see or feel the hooks even though they covered the surface. If the hooks were infinitesimally small they would be there on the 2d surface but undetectable. It is a limp analogy, but might give you some feel for the mathematics, if you imagine that could be reproduced in higher dimensions.

Comment: Nice analogy. Similarly, the surface of a pool table covered with sandpaper is still approximately two dimensional, but the 3D nature of the rough surface will affect the motion of the pool balls.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely no reasonable answer to your question.

Either you can't experience extra dimensions, or you do experience them and don't recognize them as dimensions.

If you can't experience them, what makes them different from the dimensions you can experience? Well, how would anybody know? Our concept of the dimensions you can experience is that they go off to infinity. A dimension that was "tiny" but still went off to infinity, would not be tiny. It's a bogus concept.

It would have to be different some other way. Well, we can think of three space dimensions as a length and two angles. Maybe the other dimensions are somehow rotational dimensions where if you rotate enough you come back to your original angle. But why don't we experience them? I dunno.

Maybe for some reason there is no evolutionary advantage to experiencing the other dimensions so we just didn't evolve that way. Maybe for organisms evolved in some other environment (a giant zero-G gas cloud? The interior of a sun?) there would be an evolutionary advantage, and they may have senses which we lack which help them there but would not help them if they visited us here. Who knows?

Try the other approach. Everything which can be measured can be treated as another dimension. For example temperature. Since we can measure temperature, it could be a dimension. At any point and time, we could theoretically measure the temperature at that point. That's different from other dimensions. You could line up people in a straight line along one space dimension, and they could talk back and forth while they are at the same place in all the other dimensions. But you can't line up people at the same 3D place and time with different temperatures and watch them talk. We experience temperature as a sort of dependent dimension. We can only get one temperature at each point in space-time.

It's like that with most things. Except not for probability distributions. At any point in space-time you could get a probability distribution that there is an electron there, with any axis of spin. Not an actual electron which could be measured (except it can't quite by Heisenberg) but a probability distribution of possible electrons.

Maybe you could create something sensible out of that. Or maybe not.

Comment: "Either you can't experience extra dimensions, or you do experience them and don't recognize them as dimensions." -> [?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor)

Comment: "Everything which can be measured can be treated as another dimension. For example temperature. Since we can measure temperature, it could be a dimension." -> WAT. Isn't temperature the movement of matter in a three dimensional space?

Comment: It doesn't matter what we think it is. If it is something that happens independent of the spatial dimensions and time, we can add it to the list. Time and space can be treated as a 4-vector. Anything else can make it a 5-vector. One more thing to measure.

Comment: Er. Nope. IIRC temperature is already explained in a world with only four dimensions or less. Hence is not possible to consider it a dimension. It makes no sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis