# Inertia tensor for rotors

Tags: moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics, clifford-algebra

For vectors we can use Inertia tensor. But if I want to use bivectors (Rotors), what should I use for the inertia tensor? I want to make a 2d game and progressively to 4d.

Comment: My response to a question here( https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/704043/99319 ) might help, but doesn't answer your question. What you need is an equation for $\dot{\widetilde{A}}$ which uses $\widetilde{L}$, $\widetilde{A}$, and the moment of inertia tensor's equivalent in the body frame.

Comment: Not really an answer, but Section 3.4 of Doran & Lasenby's *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* text covers this topic.

Comment: If you look in the PGA Cheatsheet at (https://bivector.net/tools.html?p=3&q=0&r=1) there is a section on rigid body dynamics under **more..** that describes the inertia tensor using geometric algebra.

Comment: Someone has created a dimension independent implementations of rigid body dynamics simulator here https://enki.ws/ganja.js/examples/pga_dyn.html

Comment: @JohnAlexiou yea, thats prerty cool. i'd definitely check it. Never knew about the bivector.net website. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When modelling angular velocity and angular momentum as bivectors instead of as axial vectors, the inertia tensor is modelled as a bivector-valued function of a bivector,

$$\mathcal{I}(B)=\int d^3 x\  \rho \mathbf{x}\wedge(\mathbf{x}\cdot B)\ ,$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is a point within an object in its reference orientation, $\rho$ is the density of the object at that point, and $B$ is a bivector.

The inertia tensor takes an angular velocity as its parameter, and its value is an angular momentum, both of which are as seen in the same frame as $\mathbf{x}$. A rotor $R$ is used to convert the object's actual angular velocity at a given moment to the equivalent in the object's reference orientation, and then convert the angular momentum from the object's reference orientation back to the object's actual current orientation,
$$L=R\mathcal{I}(R^\dagger \Omega R) R^\dagger\ ,$$
where $L$ is the angular momentum bivector, and $\Omega$ is the angular velocity bivector.

The above discussion is component-free, but in most practical applications a set of basis vectors will be chosen, in terms of which the inertia tensor can be represented in its familiar matrix form, with elements
$$\mathcal{I}_{ij}=-(I e_i)\cdot\mathcal{I}(I e_j)\ ,$$
where $I$ is the 3D unit pseudoscalar. Calculating $\mathcal{I}(\Omega_b)$, with $\Omega_b$ a bivector, then amounts to multiplying the matrix by $-I\Omega_b$, the vector dual to the $\Omega_b$ bivector. The result of the matrix multiplication is the vector dual to the bivector $\mathcal{I}(\Omega_b)$.

For more information, see section 3.4 of *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* by Doran and Lasenby.